# How can I get CoreBluetooth delegates to work after moving them to a separate class?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, core-bluetooth

I have created a small project to test `Bluetooth` using `CoreBluetooth` `framework`. In my `viewController` it works fine like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myCentral: CBCentralManager! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    }
}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if let name = peripheral.name {
            print(name)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would like to move move the `Bluetooth` stuff to another `class` and just run it from  the `viewController`. Is that possible? My attempt doesn't work:

In the New `class`, having moved the `Bluetooth` stuff:

```
class BLEhandler: NSObject {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
}

extension BLEhandler: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if let name = peripheral.name {
            print(name)
        }
        print(peripheral.name)
    }
}
```

And calling it from the `viewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var centralManager = BLEhandler().centralManager
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
```

Now it shows nothing but a small `log`:

> [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid

I doubt I can use `delegates` like this, and I think the solution has something to do with protocols, but I'm not sure. How would you go about moving over `delegates` to other `classes` and still get them to work?

Comment: Maybe your BLEHandler is being deallocated when viewDidLoad exits. Make it a property of your viewController to keep it around.

Comment: @FryAnEgg Could you elaborate a bit please? Not quite sure I understand what you mean :)

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it to work by simply declaring it first in `ViewController`:

```
var centralManager: BLEhandler!
```

then in `viewDidLoad` I `initialized` it:

```
centralManager = BLEhandler()
```

rather than directly `initializing` it in `viewDidLoad`.